# Software for sharing/exchanging locations? Visual location survey

Tags: maps, collaboration, sharing, polls, visualization

Use case: People who know each other from somewhere but not as neighbors want to know if any of them live near each other. To do things together with or count on the help of other people from the group with might live nearby.

I am thinking of something like a straw poll or those group scheduling apps but with a map with dots for each person who participated in the location survey.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some form builders like [formdesigner.pro](https://formdesigner.pro/news/new-form-field-address-and-google-map.html) that support adding maps. They will be almost all freemium though, but whether they meet your needs depends on many factors, such as how many people will need to fill the form out.

Alternatively, create your own [Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/) and allow people to edit it.